# Pfsense Virtual IP NATing

Tags: nat, pfsense, virtual-ip

Am setting up Pfsense 2.0 but am stuck when it comes to port forwarding/Natting. I've done it before but not using Virtual IPs.

Say I have WAN on 11.11.11.1 and LAN on 192.168.5.5, I have added a virtual IP 192.168.4.5 on the LAN NIC of type "Proxy ARP"

Now, I have a web server in this LAN that is 192.168.4.6. I want it accessible from the WAN.

What kind of configuration should I do?

I've put a NAT with destination WAN being redirected to 192.168.4.6. However, it fails.

What configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your wan address as your external ip address then you just go Firewall > Nat and port forward. From there you can forward your proxy. See a good guide [here](http://griffeltavla.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/pfsense-2-0-port-forwarding/) .

On my setup I have a bunch of ip addresses, which are setup as virtual ips. I then setup a 1:1 rule on that ip, to bind that wan address to a local ip. Then add the rules into the firewall to allow given ports out onto the internet.

Hope this helps.